# How to read the outputs of invoked commaned line in python?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I'm going to use subprocess to invoke a command line:

```
wgsim <input> <output1> <output2>
```

I know I can read output1 and output2 on the disk after the command line is finished. Is there a way that I can read output1 and output2 on the fly?

Thanks.

Comment: See the `communicate()` method at https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: As far as I can tell `wgsim` doesn't support any modes that would allow you to do that. It requires the two output files and cannot output to to stdout. Would [`select`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/select.html) do what you want?

Comment: Thanks. I'll check these communicate() and select.